# Checked html form boxes are NULL

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form, but when these things are checked, only Aggregation is posting a 1 as value, the others, even when checked by user are not posting. Entry.php is getting only NULL for these values.

form.html

```
    <form id="submit_entry" action="entry.php" method="post">

    <label for=dataFunc>What data functions does this organization/initiative provide? <br></label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="aggregation" value=1> Aggregation<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="production" value=1> Production<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="analysis" value=1> Analysis<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="advocacy" value=1> Advocacy<br>

    <span = "submit><input type="submit"></span>
    </form>
```

entry.php

```
    <?php
    $aggregation = $_POST["aggregation"]; 
    $production = $POST_["production"];
    $advocacy = $POST_["advocacy"];
    $analysis = $POST_["analysis"];
    $type = gettype($aggregation);
    echo "  Aggregation: " . $aggregation . " is data type " . $type . "<br>";
    $type = gettype($production);
    echo "  Production: " . $production . " is data type " . $type . "<br>";
    $type = gettype($advocacy);
    echo "  Advocacy: " . $advocacy . " is data type " . $type . "<br>";
    $type = gettype($analysis);
    echo "  Analysis: " . $analysis . " is data type " . $type . "<br>";
    ?>
```

on the form

[image]

result from processing post, echoed variable and gettype()

[image]

Comment: You need to show the php code too

Comment: Post your PHP please.

Comment: Thanks, added the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have underscores in the wrong places :

```
                   ▼
$production = $POST_["production"];
$advocacy = $POST_["advocacy"];
$analysis = $POST_["analysis"];
```

Should be :

```
               ▼
$production = $_POST["production"];
$advocacy = $_POST["advocacy"];
$analysis = $_POST["analysis"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! My brain has turned into mush and I couldn't see it. That's exactly the difference between the fields that are working and the fields that are not working.